# replacing many elements of a data.table in r

Tags: r, data.table

I have a list of words (~25,000 of them) each of which I need to 1) find in a bunch of text files (I have been reading them in and formatting them to data.tables) and 2) replace each of these words with the word 'unk'.

if each unwanted word is in a list called `wordList`, and each word has a space before and after the word, for example:

```
" aaaa "        " aaaahhhhh "   " aaaahhhhhh "  " aaas "        " aaasmtg "     " aachallenge "
```

Would the best way be to use gsub in a loop, as shown here?

```
for (i in 1:length(wordList)) {
    Lines<-as.data.table(gsub(pattern=wordList[i], replacement=' unk ', Lines))
}
```

I can currently do this, but I have hundreds of (small) files to process, and I am looping through 25,000+ words, that it will take days to complete on my little laptop.  I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this using data.tables, or if I am best using another tool/method than r?

Comment: Just a thought, you can join strings in a single `gsub` call like `gsub(" aaaa | aaas | aaasmtg "," unk ",Lines)` , which you can simplify like: `gsub(paste(wordlist,collapse="|"),"unk",Lines)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think rather than a loop through all of the wordlist you need to identify which rows have strings in the word list then simply replace them:

```
Lines[Lines %in% wordlist]<-' unk '
```